# Build a string from an EntityCollection

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, concatenation

Is there a more efficient way to do this using LINQ or `String.Join`?

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var s in cls.Students)
  sb.Append("<div id=\"s" + s.Id + "\">" + s.FirstName +
            " " + s.LastName + "</div>");
```

Comment: Data is validated before it goes into the database, and `cls` takes data straight from the database on the same server as the web app (it's an Intranet app). I don't see the opportunity for XSS?

Comment: My web app only allows certain characters to be input. Admittedly if data is entered direct to MySql (i.e. not through the app) then things could go pear shaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`string.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9c94ey1.aspx):

```
string result = string.Concat(cls.Students.Select(
    s => string.Format("<div id=\"s{0}\">{1} {2}</div>", s.Id, s.FirstName, s.LastName)
));
```

It's a little more concise, but it probably won't give you more performance. Using a `StringBuilder` is already very efficient.

**Notes**

- In .NET 3.5 and older you will also need to add `.ToArray()` just before the last parenthesis.
- You should HTML escape `s.FirstName` and `s.LastName`. I'm assuming `s.ID` is an integer and therefore is safe.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to escape them even if `cls` takes data straight from a database which I know contains validated data?

Comment: @James: It would be a very good idea. They might be validated today, but that may change in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done something like this.

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
cls.Students.ForEach(s => builder.Append(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(string.Format("<div id=\"{0}\">{1} {2}</div>", s.Id, s.FirstName, s.LastName)));
```

Comment: `.ForEach` isn't coming up in my IntelliSense - do I need to add a reference?

Comment: cls.Students is a list of students isn't it? ForEach is a part of the System.Collections.Generic namespace.

Comment: It's an `EntityCollection`, but I can `ToList()` it, which solves the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

vb in

```
Dim XXX As System.Xml.Linq.XElement = <div id=<%="s" + s.Id %> ><%= s.FirstName  %> <%= s.LastName  %></div>
```

No quotation